# Primary key value doesn't increment auto in Entity framwork database

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-5

I am sure m missing something really small but i am having issue of Primary value auto incremental. I have creates two simple table and I have adopt Existing database model first approach by using Entity Framework 5. I simple adding values in table from console program.

My issue is code works fine for first time, but crashes if i try to add more value by running whole app again and i found the reason; the EF doesn't increment primary index automatically.

### table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Book_Titles] (
[Book_ID] INT            NOT NULL,
[Title]   NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Book_ID] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Books_Authors] (
[Author_Id]   INT            NOT NULL,
[Author_Name] NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
[Book_ID]     INT            NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Author_Id] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([Book_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Book_Titles] ([Book_ID])
);
```

### Console program

```
namespace Database_First_01
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        using (var db = new BooksContext())
        {
            var book = new Book_Titles()
            {
                Title ="EF ",
            };

            var author = new Books_Authors()
            {
                Author_Name = "me!",
            };

            book.Books_Authors.Add(author);
            db.Book_Titles.Add(book);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
}
```

many thanks in advance.

Comment: there are no identity columns in your sql script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Book_Titles] (
  [Book_ID] INT   IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
  [Title]   NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Book_ID] ASC)
);
```

Define `Identity` on Column

Same as other if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server uses the `IDENTITY` keyword to perform an auto-increment feature. and its missing in your case.

You can use `IDENTITY` property in different cases

- Its used with the CREATE TABLE
- and ALTER TABLE Transact-SQL statements.

so if you have already created the table ( and it has data ) you may just alter like as follow.

```
 ALTER TABLE (yourTable) ADD NewColumn INT IDENTITY(1,1)
 ALTER TABLE (yourTable) DROP COLUMN OldColumnName
 sp_rename 'yourTable.NewColumn', 'OldColumnName', 'COLUMN'
```

and it will save your data in the existing table.

Hope it will help